# Migration: previous URL redirection after migrating

Tags: wordpress, migration

I read all the other questions about this issue, I did all that was recommended yet I can't find the solution, the current WP installation keeps redirecting to the previous domain. I am running WP in Docker, I dumped the DB from the previous site and did the following:

I replaced all the https://oldurl.com with my new HTTP://local.url:8080 using sed. (local.url is declared in /etc/hosts)

I added to the wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://local.url:8080');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://local.url:8080');
define('RELOCATE',true);
```

I ran "Search and Replace DB" to replace all the iterations of the previous domain.

I search for an occurrence of the old domain in the DB and in the files, no occurrence was found. 5)I checked for .htaccess, it has the standard WP htaccess, no reference to any domain.

I clear the cookies + cache of the browser.

I tested the URL in 3 different browsers.

I don't have any cache plugin active.

After doing all these, when I type the URL it keeps redirecting me to the old URL, yet if I try local.url:8080/wp-admin, the site works correctly, the front-end doesn't work but the backend does. Any suggestion on what else could I try?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this plugin for migration https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Comment: I tried, same thing, I can't figure out why it keeps redirecting to the old URL

Comment: Try change template to default, and check redirect work or not

Comment: I did yet the same issue persists.